# Wrong voltage in op amp circuit to adc

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, current-measurement

my circuit is not giving me the expected voltage. This is used to measure the current flowing trought the shunt.

[image]

For example: if I expect 1.3, I get about 1,15V out. Anyone knows what I did wrong?

edit: the resistor is 5k of course, not 5000k

The voltage was measured with a multimeter.

Comment: It would be useful to know the output at 2 or 3 points.  For example at zero current, half scale and full scale.  Have you looked at the output with a scope to see if there is oscillation or noise?  The difference between 1.15 and 1.3v is not very much.  Does the sense resistor have a Kelvin connection?

Comment: No circuit is ideal. Have you calculated the expected accuracy over full-scale (percentage of error)? What's the tolerance of the sense resistor?

Comment: @KevinWhite at zero input there is no voltage I can measure. There is a bit oscillation, but that comes from the ADC. At least it looks like the typical curve of an ADC.

Comment: The accuracy of the shunt is 1%, This wouldn't explain the missing 0,150V :/ @DigitalNinja

Comment: I can't find any data on op-amp 'MCP33172'. Is it actually an MC33172? What part number is the transistor? Have you examined the output with a 'scope, does it look stable?

Comment: Is it a 4-terminal shunt?

Comment: @Bruce Abbot:yes, sorry, its the mc...  The transistor is a bc847. I will check the supply of the op amp tomorrow, whether its stable,thanks.

Comment: @Kevin White, no regular 2 terminal shunt

Comment: With a 2 terminal shunt you have to be very careful that you don't introduce additional voltage due to the resistance of the soldered joint.  If it is on a PCB there are layouts that can minimize the error.  Or ideally you would use a 4-terminal  (Kelvin connected) shunt.

Comment: @canbus - measure voltage across shunt (should be 78mV @ 7.8A). Disconnect ADC and measure output voltage, check that it is stable (no 'oscillation').

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess here but 5K is not a standard E96 value - are you **sure** it's not 4.42K, which is a standard value?

Anyway, assuming that's not it- to debug it, read the voltage across the shunt with a voltmeter (preferably with 0.1mV resolution or better and >10M input resistance). Most inexpensive handheld meters are fine. If it's not 78.0mV +/- shunt tolerance (measured between the sense connections, not the force connections), then you have at least one problem. As in a comment make sure you've used a 4-wire type shunt and are using it correctly (though problems here would tend to lead to a higher output).

When that's okay, read the voltage across the op-amp inputs. It should read 0.0mV.

If that's okay, **disconnect the ADC** and read the voltage across the 5.00K resistor. It should read 1.30V +/- all the tolerances (taking Vos of the op-amp into account), plus a few tenths of a percent for BJT hFE.

If that's okay, then it could be loading the by the ADC. Some ADCs have input impedance in the range that would explain your symptoms (~38K).

Answer (score 0):

You are after high accuracy  BUT there is a base current error that could plausibly explain only 1% error BUT your 10m ohm shunt only develops 78mV at 7.8 Amp this low voltage will be too errorprone  SO increase the shunt resistors value to reduce errors NOW if you cant waste more voltage then think about a HALL effect device